# using an EJB 3.1 bean through a remote java stand-alone application

Tags: rmi, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, corba, netbeans-7

I have been trying to use Java EE 6 to create an Application Server based app which is to receive Job objects from a GWT Web Application and those Jobs would be pulled from a Java stand-alone application. I have been thinking that the EJB model would provide me with easy way to do remoting because my client app should be able to run on a different machine.

I am using Glassfish 3.1 and Netbeans 7.0.1 as my IDE, I have also used eclipse Java EE to reproduce same problem.

I have been facing the next difficulties:

- It was not easy to find out about `InitialContext`, is it the only way to use the remoting? shouldn't I be able to use `@EJB`/`@Inject` for some automatic code injection from my stand alone app using some configuration file?
- I have discovered some how (not found directly in documentation) that for the `InitialContext` mechanism to work I need to add to my Libraries: `gf-client-module.jar` and `weld-osgi-bundle.jar`
- I have been receiving the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: IOP00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at ContentCreator._JobDispatcherRemote_Wrapper.getSimpleJobForProcessing(ContentCreator/_JobDispatcherRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:35)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446343 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: IOP00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at ContentCreator.__JobDispatcherRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getSimpleJobForProcessing(ContentCreator/__JobDispatcherRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: IOP00810007: Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(BufferManagerReadStream.java:128)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(CDRInputStream_1_1.java:113)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:126)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1810)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1040)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:384)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:203)
    ... 5 more
```

I have been facing problems with using Java EE 6 remotely in my scenario and have found little help for those problems any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In my case i have the same stack message "Underflow in BufferManagerReadStream after last fragment in message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7"

In my project i had a nested object which not implements the Serializable interface. Implementing the Inteface solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take care that the class of the object that you pass as argument while rmi-invoking the method getSimpleJobForProcessing implements the interface java.io.Serializable?
This was one reason, why I had such exceptions, too.

Answer (score 0):

The @EJB annotation is processed and interpreted by a Java EE compliant container, so as far as I know there is no simple way to do this from a Java application that doesn't run in a container.

However, if you are running from a Glassfish container, you might be able to get rid of the JNDI lookup.

You can try the following:

```
@EJB(name = "RemoteService") 
private StatusService remoteService;
```

and then in your sun-web.xml:

```
   <ejb-ref> 
            <ejb-ref-name>RemoteService</ejb-ref-name> 
            <jndi-name>java:comp/env/com//RemoteService</jndi-name> 
    </ejb-ref>
```

With the exception, I cannot help.

Comment: this does not address the exception... which is my biggest worry

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I stated in my reply. I ansewered your question about the @EJB annotation but cannot help with the exception.